# External IP addresses gcp console and API count mismatch

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, ip-address, reserved-ip-addresses

Here on console, I am able to see a total of 7 resources. Which does not match with the result got from the API call. With API calls I am getting 75 resources:

[image: External IP addresses]

**GCP Doc link**
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/list

**Method GET:**
`https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/regions/{region}/addresses`

Here for `us-east1` UI console shows 1 entry and API gives 4 records.

**EDIT**

For region `us-east1` there are 4 records:

[image: API response for region]

Comment: Could you provide output of the API request? I've tried on my test project and it works good for me.

Comment: Yes @SerhiiRohoza i have added response

Comment: Thanks! On the screenshot you provided I can see EXTERNAL IPs, but at the API I can see INTERNAL IPs. So, maybe it's a reason for the difference in results.

Comment: Does it mean the APIs must be different. As per Official documentation result on the GCP console should match with, result from the API call.

Comment: Just set the proper `items[].addressType` as it's described at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/list`).

Comment: Are you counting the external or internal IP? I'm lost here!

Comment: Have you solved your issue with setting proper `items[].addressType`?

Comment: Out of 75 from API calls, only 2 are shown on the console, which is of type `static`. Here for asia-east1 1 of type `static` matched in UI and API and 4 are of `Ephemeral` does not match up in API.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza No, `items[].addressType` This helps to get a specific type(INTERNAL, EXTERNAL), what I notice is we do not get `Ephemeral` type via region-specific APIs.

Comment: Accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/list) for this API request: `items[].address` `string` "The **static** IP address represented by this resource". So, it's expected that you didn't get any `Ephemeral`.

Comment: Yes, noticed @SerhiiRohoza Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you! I posted an answer (as a summary of research here), please accept/upvote if my assistance was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was discussed at the comment section, you see mismatch between Cloud Console ([image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0XwO.png)) and API request ([image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xn8p.png)) because UI shows you EXTERNAL IP and API shows INTERNAL IP.

*To solve this issue* you should follow API documentation [`Method: addresses.list`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/list) and set required `items[].addressType`:

> The type of address to reserve, either INTERNAL or EXTERNAL. If unspecified, defaults to EXTERNAL.

Furthermore, you can see EPHEMERAL IP via Cloud Console UI, but accordingly to the API documentation [`items[].address`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/list):

> The *static* IP address represented by this resource.